# Custom filters in laravel-ffmpeg/ php-ffmpeg?

Tags: php, laravel, ffmpeg-php

I wanna create custom command using php-ffmpeg/laravel-ffmpeg?

```php
$customFilter = ['-stream_loop 3'];
$customFilter1 = ['-c copy'];
\FFMpeg::fromDisk($this->data['input_disk'])
    ->open($this->data['input'])
    ->addFilter(function ($filters) {
            $filters->custom($customFilter);
            $filters->custom($customFilter1);
     })
    ->export()
    ->toDisk($this->data['output_disk'])
    ->inFormat(new \FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264('libmp3lame', 'libx264'))
    ->save($this->data['output']);
```

> local.ERROR: Encoding failed {"exception":"[object] (FFMpeg\Exception\RuntimeException(code: 0):

Comment: ->addFilter(new FFMpeg\Filters\Audio\SimpleFilter($customFilter))
->addFilter(new FFMpeg\Filters\Audio\SimpleFilter($customFilter1)) should be ->addFilter(new \FFMpeg\Filters\Audio\SimpleFilter($customFilter))
    ->addFilter(new \FFMpeg\Filters\Audio\SimpleFilter($customFilter1))

Comment: missing \ from the package name.

Comment: i have added the \ but still the same error occurs. Is there any other way to process the custom filters in php-ffmpeg?

Comment: just to confirm... when you try the code without custom filters...does this work?

Comment: Hi @VikashPathak i need a loop video/ repeat video with multiple times, when am trying in cmd it is working but in the laravel-ffmpeg i dont know how to set the custom filters for loop the video, Can you please give an idea?

Comment: please paste the command that is working for you.

Answer (score 1):

Please try if this could help to you. As per the fix given here...use **string start/end with space instead of array**.

https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg/issues/381#issuecomment-314150217

```
$customFilter = ' -stream_loop 3 ';
$customFilter1 = ' -c copy ';
\FFMpeg::fromDisk($this->data['input_disk'])
    ->open($this->data['input'])
    ->addFilter(function ($filters) {
            $filters->custom($customFilter);
            $filters->custom($customFilter1);
     })
    ->export()
    ->toDisk($this->data['output_disk'])
    ->inFormat(new \FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264('libmp3lame', 'libx264'))
    ->save($this->data['output']);
```

Comment: or just combine both of custom filters with multiple string. like $filters->custom(' -stream_loop 3 ', ' -c copy '); As per documentation in filter section.. https://github.com/pascalbaljetmedia/laravel-ffmpeg

Comment: /usr/bin/ffmpeg' '-y' '-i' '/tmp/laravel-ffmpega8wlU2' '-threads' '12' '-vcodec' 'libx264' '-acodec' 'libmp3lame' '-b:v' '1000k' '-refs' '6' '-coder' '1' '-sc_threshold' '40' '-flags' '+loop' '-me_range' '16' '-subq' '7' '-i_qfactor' '0.71' '-qcomp' '0.6' '-qdiff' '4' '-trellis' '1' '-b:a' '128k' '-vf' '[in]-stream_loop 3[out]' '-pass' '1' '-passlogfile' '/tmp/ffmpeg-passes5ced2891df501t4ckr/pass-5ced2891eddea' '/tmp/laravel-ffmpegBdgpn7.mp4'   This is the command returned with error.

Comment: remove one filter and try with only one.  $filters->custom(' -stream_loop  ', 3);

Comment: the above direct custom also not work properly @vikash

Comment: @vasanth do share the output of this cmd and the cmd that working for you... what is differece b/w both?